# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '328.94'(while converting bytes to int())

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, byte, arduino-uno

This is my code:

```
import serial

print('Arduino is setting up')
# Setting up the Arduino board

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com4', 9600)
while True:
    if arduinoSerialData.inWaiting() > 1:
        myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()
        myData = str(myData)
        myData = myData.replace("b'", '')
        myData = myData.replace("\\r\\n'", '')
        myData1=myData
        if myData1.find("a"):
            myData1= myData1.replace("a",str(0))
            if int(myData1)<100:
                print(myData)
```

What this code does is it imports the data from the ultrasonic sensor thats attached to the arduino board, and prints it.`myData` is initially in bytes so I convert it to string, but I cannot seem to convert it to `int`.When I tried the above code, I get try this code, I get this error.Anyone know how to troubleshoot this?Thanks!

Comment: Use `float()` instead?

Comment: Wow ok that surprisingly works, but is there a proper way to convert this to float?I tried the methods given online but they didnt work

Comment: You don't tell us what the format of the data returned is, you have to check the documentation of the hardware/code you use if you didn't write it yourself. If the value is a float, and is returned as a string as it seems to be the case, then this is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that your bytes to string conversion is not correct. Why not try this:

```
1. Bytes to string conversion:
   mydata  = myData.decode("utf-8")

2. Eliminatinf trailing newline characters:
   myData = myData.strip("\r\n")
```

Make sure that that the resulting string contains only numeric characters to get converted to int. You can do this check :

```
if mydata1.isdigit() and int(mydata1) < 100:
    <your code>
```

If ur string contains float number,then u can  perform do this:

```
if mydata1.replace(".", "").isdigit() and int(float(mydata1)) < 100:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give a *string* to `int()`, it needs to be an integer. If you instead have a non-integer, you can convert it with `float()` first, *then* use `int()` to turn that floating point value into an integer, as per the following transcript:

```
>>> print(int("328.94"))               # Will not work.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '328.94'

>>> print(float("328.94"))             # Convert string to float.
328.94

>>> print(int(float("328.94")))        # Convert string to float to int.
328

>>> print(int(float("328.94") + 0.5))  # Same but rounded.
329
```

That last one is an option if you want it rounded to the nearest integer, rather than truncated.